# Gmail does not recognize valign nor vertical-align

Tags: html-email, vertical-alignment, valign

I'm making an e-mail template. I want to make a line below the heroImage.jpg. The line cannot be a part of the heroImage.jpg as there are several other lines in the e-mail and they should all look the same.

The way I do it is that I set a border-bottom to a table row in which heroImage.jpg is placed.

My problem is that in GMAIL (when the e-mail is delivered, but not in OUTLOOK for example) I get a thin ribbon of space between heroImage.jpg and my line. I think it is because GMAIL does not recognize valign nor vertical-align and thus the heroImage.jpg is aligned top (probably default option) and the colour of #heroImageBlock is thus visible.

But how it should be is that heroImage.jpg would be aligned bottom and right below to it would be my line (no annoying space in between).

Is there a way to force GMAIL to recognize valign or vertical-align and get rid of that annoying space?

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="bottom" id="heroImageContainer">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="heroImageBlock">                                      
            <tr class="border-bottom">
                <td>
                    <img src="images/heroImage.jpg" alt="" height="150" width="600" id="heroImage" />
                </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
#heroImageBlock td{vertical-align:bottom;}
```

I've tried to assign vertical align to all other elements too (see below) but it does not work.

```
#heroImageContainer {vertical-align:bottom;}
#heroImageBlock{vertical-align:bottom;}
#heroImageBlock tr{vertical-align:bottom;}
```

In OUTLOOK image and a red line are nicely together as it should be:

[image]

In GMAIL there is an annoying gray line between the image and the red line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Valign/vertical align isn't your issue here. Since you're specifically setting a block image, you shouldn't have anything to vertically align. This points to another issue to do with the way you're declaring the image, but I'll get to that soon.

FYI, it's best if you give us more scope or more code. You're referencing a border-bottom class, but we can't see what properties to render that border are. Same goes for the id on the image. If any properties are being set on classes or IDs in the head, it's best to include those for us to help you debug.

Here are my suggested improvements to try and fix this.
 1. Don't set any properties or classes on table rows. They aren't designed for that use. Moving the border may fix the issue but even if it doesn't, tables and table cells are where you should be adding these. In this case, move the border-bottom class declaration to the table cell under the row.
 2. Have you tried setting display:block; on the image? By default, images will be declared as inline and you have to specifically set is as block. When inline, spacing can appear below images and will throw spacing and dimensions out when trying to be pixel perfect, or in your case aligning content directly below.

Let me know how those go.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Here is the link to the entire file http://www.ortodroma.si/dowloadable/email-V08.html. The code should have been of quite a good quality in general as I have build it following Treehouse template made by a Mailchimp wizzard, but you never know. I have placed border-bottom to table data and tried sending again to Gmail. The problem remains.

Comment: P.S. I definitely do not think someone should go and study the whole code. But It is very hard for me to even know which part of code to send you. But I will definitely think of some way. I have attached the entire code of the e-mail just in case.

Comment: Sorry, won't let me open that link. Are you able to jump into the code and add the display:block on the image manually?

Comment: I have also tried your suggestion nr 2 ( I have added display:block to the image) but it does not work either. I did it like this: <img src="https://www.ortodroma.si/downloadable/new.jpg" alt="Section separator" height="11" width="50" id="separatorImage" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block">

Comment: Thanks for staying with me :) The correct link is: http://www.ortodroma.si/downloadable/email-V08.html ----- It was a typo.

Comment: Which Outlook are you seeing the issue in? I'm currently testing in Litmus and can't replicate the issue

Comment: Hi, on latest version of Outlook (16.0 if that help; I pay for it once a year so it is the latest version). But on Outlook it works fine. It is Gmail that is the problem. And by the way also Yahoo. In Gmail and Yahoo there is that annoying gray space between the image and the red line. But I would want it to look like it does in Outlook. Please see the two attached images above (Outlook is fine; Gmail is the problem).

Comment: Hey mate, honestly I can't find anything else it could be. The only consistent solution  (across all email clients) from my point of view is adding display:block inline, to the image. Are you able to check the output HTML and confirm the display:block is coming through when sent?

Comment: Saw your code, add display block to the image in a style and it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these styles to the parent element:
font-size:0px and line-height:0px. 
By default Gmail tends to add its own spacing. The above should remove it.

Comment: What accessibility flags would using `font-size:0` throw? When specifying values of zero in CSS the unit isn't needed and will fail many CSS linters.